# dealloc method gone from the ViewController implementation file template in Xcode 4?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ios4, xcode4

I'm new to iOS development.

From the book I'm reading, I understand that Outlets need to be released in two places in the ViewController implementation file (.m).

Like this:

```
- (void)viewDidUnload {
    self.statusText = nil;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [statusText release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Apple automatically adds these two methods (viewDidUnload and dealloc) to the implementation file when you create a new project.

However, I noticed that with the new Xcode 4 the "dealloc" method does not seem to be there?

Is this something I should add manually or has Apple maybe removed the need to release the outlets in two places?

Anyone know?  Thanks!

Comment: Hmmm, that doesn't seem right: if `viewDidUnload` is called before `dealloc` (which it presumably does), then `statusText` is never released (because the release message is sent to nil)

Comment: @bosmacs `self.statusText = nil;` will release the object

Comment: Sorry, the property syntax threw me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you have created a project that uses the new ARC (Automatic Reference Counting) and therefore do not need the dealloc method because calling `retain` or `release` is no longer allowed when compiling with this option.

Comment: My outlets are declared in the header file like this  @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel  *statusText;  Is that correct how I should declare them?  I'm not getting an error from the debugger

Comment: @FreeAsinBeer is correct and you are declaring them properly. Under ARC you still need to declare properties in that fashion to get the benefits of property and synthesize